# Primefaces: Traer Fecha actual

Tags: java, primefaces

necesito que el campo llamado fechaCompra me traiga la fecha actual en el p:datePicker ya que solo me permite seleccionar fechas mas no me aparece la fecha actual y si es posible tener una condicion aparte para que solo me permita seleccionar 6 dias anteriores al actual

```js
if (detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion() != null && !detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion().isEmpty()) {
  for (GenericoStringDto forma: formasGeneracion) {
    if (forma.getId().equals(detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion())) {
      periodoFac = new PeriodoDeFacturacion();
      periodoFac.setCodigoDescripcion(forma.getId());
      periodoFac.setDescripcion(forma.getDescripcion());
  periodoFac.setFechaCompra(Utilidades.getFormattedDate(detalle.getFechaCompra()));
      LOGGER.error("datos formageneracion " + periodoFac.getCodigoDescripcion() + " " +
        periodoFac.getDescripcion() + " " + periodoFac.getFechaCompra());
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">

  <h:outputLabel for="id_fechaCompra" value="Fecha de compra*" />
  <p:datePicker id="id_fechaCompra" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" 
      value="#{crearDocumentoEmisionView.detalle.fechaCompra}" 
      required="true" 
      requiredMessage="Ingrese la fecha de compra" 
      yearNavigator="true" yearRange="2000:2030" 
      monthNavigator="true" showIcon="true"
      showButtonBar="true" mask="true" navigator="true" 
      locale="es" readonlyInput="true" />
  <p:message for="id_fechaCompra">
    <p:autoUpdate></p:autoUpdate>
  </p:message>
</div>
```

gracias

Comment: Código cómo texto, por favor.

Comment: ya lo actualice en una respuesta gracias

Comment: Las respuestas son eso, respuestas. Tu pregunta va en... la zona de pregunta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio . 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante como [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: listo ya la edite lo mejor que pude muchas gracias

Comment: ehh Me parece que enredaste la explicación "me traiga la fecha actual en el p:datePicker" a que te refieres con eso?

Comment: es el campo donde tengo la fecha perdon por el enredo

Comment: Pero quieres obtener la fecha del datepicker?? o quieres ingresar la fecha actual en él??

Comment: que en el datepicker me aparezca la fecha actual

Comment: Restringe la selección con maxDateCout="6" y si quieres restringir desde la fecha seleccionada hasta 6 días atrás tienes que jugar con minDate y maxDate en el evento onChange o ValueChangeListener o p:ajax dateSelect. La fecha actual asignala en el PostConstruct